# Add two divs on the same page, each containing a link which hides it's parent div and shows the other one

Tags: javascript, css

What i want is: A single html page, containing two divs, each of which contains a link. The page loads showing only one specific div. When the link inside one div is cliked, it's parent div is hidden and the other one is shown. What i have done so far is this (it's a Frankenstein script based on 2-3 other scripts i found here and there):

https://jsfiddle.net/cyberlord64/shcLhrqx/

but the problem is that the first time i press to show the second div, both are seen at the same time. After that the rotation is normal.

What is the problem? Is it possible to simplify further the process? is it possible to do this only with css?

The HTML

```
<div class="main">
<div id="page1" class="content">
<h1>Login</h1>
<form>
  Username:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br> 
  Password:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#" data-page="page2">click to register</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="hidden-content">
<h1>Register</h1>
<form>
  Username:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br> 
  Password:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"> 
  <br>
  Repeat password:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"> 
  <br>
  Email:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#" data-page="page1">Click to login</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The JS

```
$(function() {
var curPage = "";
$("#menu a").click(function() {
if (curPage.length) {
  $("#" + curPage).hide();
}
curPage = $(this).data("page");
$("#" + curPage).show();
});
});
```

The CSS

```
.hidden-content {
display: none;
}
```

Thanx.

Comment: set your var curPage = "page1" instead of "". https://jsfiddle.net/shcLhrqx/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do -

1. give your content-holders a class
2. use the href attribute on your links - #idOfDivToShow (then it will also be more accessible)
3. give your links a class
4. put the above together and then you can use the following simple jQuery:

```js
var content = $('.content'),
    links = $('.link');

links.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  content.hide();  // hide all content blocks
  $($(this).attr('href')).show(); // show targetted content
})
```

```css
.content {display:none;} /*hide all pages*/ 
#page1 {display:block;} /*show starting page*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div id="page1" class="content">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form>
      Username:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname">
      <br>Password:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </form>
    <div id="menu">
      <a href="#page2" data-page="page2" class="link">click to register</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="page2" class="content">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form>
      Username:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname">
      <br>Password:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname">
      <br>Repeat password:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname">
      <br>Email:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </form>
    <div id="menu">
      <a href="#page1" data-page="page1" class="link">Click to login</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way, you can add as many pages as you want and have a nav menu

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your jQuery as below and also modified your attributes of `<a>` to `data-page-show` and `data-page-hide`.

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/shcLhrqx/2/)

```
$(function() {
  $("#menu a").click(function() {
    var show = $(this).attr('data-page-show');
    var hide = $(this).attr('data-page-hide');
    $('#' + hide).hide();
    $('#' + show).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Interesting. I was wondering if i could remove the div around those <a> tags for a cleaner code... Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You want to hide clicked parent div and show the other one? Basically, you want to use toggle() (or slideToggle() depending of what kind of effect you want to achieve). It will hide the div if it's visible, and show it if it's not.

Also you should avoid using same #id on the page multiple times (#menu in your example). By definition id-s are reserved for DOM elements that are unique on the page, use classes if you need to use multiple selectors of the same name.

```
$(function() {
  var curPage = "";
  $(".menu a").click(function() {
    var page = $(this).closest('.page');
    page.slideToggle(300);
    page.siblings().slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shcLhrqx/3/)

The code above first, finds all of the `.page` elements, then hides the clicked one, and then toggles the state (in this case shows) of all of its siblings (elements that are in the same hierarchy)

Comment: Thank you! +1 for pointing out the possibility to add an effect which i might use in the future!